# MySQL ignore (near) duplicates based on field value

Tags: mysql

I have a table I'm dealing with that handles "tickets" (status = "open" or  status = "closed").   When a ticket is closed, instead of changing the status, the system involved creates a duplicate entry with a "closed" status.

With a key field of "ticket_number", how could I modify the query below to ignore any status = "open" items if another record for the same "ticket_number" field exists with a "closed" status?

I can't use "DISTINCT" and I'm a little lost on how to selectively filter (near) duplicate records from a query based on a field value.

Thanks for any help.

```
SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS item_number, t.*
FROM test t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt := 0) AS dummy
WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND created<= NOW()
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Comment: Can tickets go from open to closed to open (etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have something in the data which identifies the order in which the ticket status changes such as an auto increment id field or date then you could select the last status event for example

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int auto_increment primary key,ticket_number int, status varchar(6));

insert into t (ticket_number,status) values
(1,'open'),(2,'open'),(2,'closed'),(3,'open'),(3,'closed'),(3,'open'),
(4,'open'),(4,'closed'),(4,'open'),(4,'closed');

select * 
from t 
where id = (select max(t1.id) from t t1 where t1.ticket_number = t.ticket_number)
        and t.status = 'open';
MariaDB [sandbox]> select *
    -> from t
    -> where id = (select max(t1.id) from t t1 where t1.ticket_number = t.ticket_number)
    -> and t.status = 'open';

+----+---------------+--------+
| id | ticket_number | status |
+----+---------------+--------+
|  1 |             1 | open   |
|  6 |             3 | open   |
+----+---------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the list into your query for the cross join.  Either use this as your FROM statement, or materialize it into a temp table and use that in your FROM.

```
SELECT * FROM(
     select a.*, b.status as closedstatus
     from test.tickets a
     left join (select ticketid, status from test.tickets where status='closed') b on a.ticketid=b.ticketid
    where a.status='open') t
WHERE closedstatus is null
```